# Getting particular strings in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I was wondering if it is possible to only read in particular parts of a string using scanf.

For example since I am reading from a file i use fscanf

if I wanted to read **name** and **number** (where number is the 111-2222) when they are in a string such as:

Bob Hardy:sometext:111-2222:sometext:sometext

I use this but its not working:

```
(fscanf(read, "%23[^:] %27[^:] %10[^:] %27[^:] %d\n", name,var1, number, var2, var3))
```

Comment: suggest `" %23[^:]: %27[^:]: %10[^:]: %27[^:]: %d"`  Add 4 `:`, Add lead space, drop trailing space - maybe (depends on code).  Still better off using `fgets()` and then parse the buffer.

Comment: ...after `fgets` use `strtok` to extract parts of the string.

Comment: can anyone explain about %23[^:] what is the usage.

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial format string fails because it does not consume the `:` delimiters.

If you want `scanf()` to read a portion of the input, but you don't care what is actually read, then you should use a field descriptor with the assignment-suppression flag (`*`):

```
char nl;
fscanf(read, "%23[^:]:%*[^:]:%10[^:]%*[^\n]%c", name, number, &nl);
```

As a bonus, you don't need to worry about buffer overruns for fields with assignment suppressed.

You should not attempt to match a single newline via a trailing newline character in the format, because a literal newline (or space or tab) in the format will match any run of whitespace.  In this particular case, it would consume not just the line terminator but also any leading whitespace on the next line.

The last field is not suppressed, even though it will almost always receive a newline, because that way you can tell from the return value if you've scanned the last line of the file and it is not newline-terminated.

Comment: Something should consume the `'\n'` else the next call of `fscanf(read, "%23[^:]...`, `name` will likely begin with `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux, I updated the format to consume the trailing `\n`, where there is one.  This is more parallel to the OP's attempt.  It will suffer a matching failure on the last line of the file if that line is not newline-terminated, but that will not affect reading the desired data.  That case can be distinguished by the return value.

Answer (score 1):

**Check `fscanf()` return value.**

`fscanf(read, "%23[^:] %27[^:] ...` is failing because after scanning the first field with `%23[^:]`, `fscanf()` encounters a `':'`.  Since that does not match the next part of the format, a white-space as in `' '`, scanning stops.

Had code checked the returned value of `fscanf()`, which was certainly 1, it may have been self-evident the source of the problem.  So the scanning needs to consume the `':'`, add it to the format: `"%23[^:]: %27[^:]: ...`

**Better to use `fgets()`**

Using `fscanf()` to read data **and** detect properly and improperly formatted data is very challenging.  It can be done correctly to scan *expected* input.  Yet it rarely works to handle some incorrectly formated input.

Instead, simple read a *line* of data and *then* parse it.  Using `'%n'` is an easy way to detect complete conversion as it saves the `char` scan count - if scanning gets there.

```
char buffer[200];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, read) == NULL) {
  return EOF;
}
int n = 0;
sscanf(buffer, " %23[^:]: %27[^:]: %10[^:]: %27[^:]:%d %n", 
    name, var1, number, var2, &var3, &n);
if (n == 0) {
  return FAIL; // scan incomplete
}
if (buffer[n]) {
  return FAIL; // Extra data on line
}
// Success!
```

Note: sample input ended with text, but original format used `"%d"`.  Unclear on OP's intent.